# What type of chart is this?

Tags: family-tree

I stumbled upon a family tree here called [Chehebar](http://www.chehebar.com/new/). It is very aesthetic. Is there a name for this type of chart, or is this a pedigree presented differently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a simple descendant chart, which shows the descendants of a particular person (Abraham Laham A"H). Another example of this is:
[image]

A pedigree chart, or ancestor chart, is one that shows the ancestors of an individual, but not typically siblings or collateral lines, such as:

[image]

There are a number of other types of charts, and sometimes the different forms can be combined to show both ancestors and descendants.